# Find the number of different $10$ digit numbers having no digit repeated and divisible by $99$.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Find the number of different $10$ digit numbers having no digit repeated and divisible by $99$.

Obviously the number is divisible by $9$ because $0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9=45$ and $45$ is divisble by $9$.

Now let the number be $a_1b_1a_2b_2a_3b_3a_4b_4a_5b_5$.

For divisbilty by $11$,  $(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5)-(b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4+b_5)=0 or 11 or 22 or 33$

I could not think anything from here. Help.

Thanks.

Comment: The maximum value of $(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5)-(b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4+b_5)$ can be only $25$. Hence the case of $33$ is useless

Comment: The difference between two integers which have an odd sum will always be odd (they have to have opposite parity).

Comment: Putting these two remarks together, either $a_1 + \cdots + a_5 = 28$ and $b_1 + \cdots + b_5 = 17$ or vice versa.

Comment: There are only thirteen groups of five that add up to 28: {9, 8, 7, 4, 0}, {9, 8, 7, 3, 1}, {9, 8, 6, 5, 0}, {9, 8, 6, 4, 1}, {9, 8, 6, 3, 2}, {9, 8, 5, 4, 2}, {9, 7, 6, 5, 1}, {9, 7, 6, 4, 2}, 
{9, 7, 5, 4, 3}, {8, 7, 6, 5, 2}, {8, 7, 6, 4, 3}